# Hyжнo ли oбocoблять «нecoмнeннo» зaпятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, наречия

*Дa и для взpocлыx здecь **нecoмнeннo** нaйдётcя чтo-тo нoвoe и интepecнoe.*

Answer (score 1):

В начале предложения это слово почти всегда является вводным. В том числе очень часто оно обособляется и в середине предложения. Однако в вашем примере все зависит от логического ударения. Допускается вариант, когда запятая не нужна: «Да и для взрослых здесь несомненно *(точно, обязательно)* найдется что-то новое и интересное».

В общем, зависит от авторского решения. Я бы, конечно, предпочел поставить запятые.